# OpenLiteSpeed blocking proxy server, do I need a Websocket?

Tags: node.js, axios, proxy, cors, airtable

First time setting up a proxy server here. I wish to send data to my Airtable database while hiding all the confidential API info using a proxy server.

I have created the proxy server and it is working great when not using Nginx but when I try to add it to my production, OpenLiteSpeed is blocking it.

I've tried following multiple posts but I am now confused and not sure what I need. I believe I need to tell OpenLiteSpeed to create a websocket but I'm unsure.

I just need a little help to get over the last hurdle.

My proxy server is on port: 5000

Here is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

// Use cors middleware
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://domain.co.uk',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // For legacy browser support
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/submit', async (req, res) => {
  const { name, age, email, amount, postcode } = req.body;

  // Prepare Airtable API request
  const airtableData = {
    records: [
      {
        fields: {
          Name: name,
          Age: age,
          Email: email,
          Amount: amount,
          Postcode: postcode
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  try {
    await axios.post(
      `https://api.airtable.com/v0/${process.env.AIRTABLE_BASE_ID}/${process.env.AIRTABLE_TABLE_ID}`,
      airtableData,
      {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.AIRTABLE_API_KEY}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    );
    res.json({ message: "Form posted to Airtable" }); // Sending success message
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error posting to Airtable:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error posting to Airtable:" }); // Sending error message
  }
});

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('../../etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co.uk/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('../../etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co.uk/cert.pem', 'utf8');
// If you have a certificate authority file, use the following line. Otherwise, you can comment or remove it.
// const ca = fs.readFileSync('path/to/ca.crt', 'utf8'); 

const credentials = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate,
  // ca: ca // Optional, only if you have a certificate authority file
};

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`HTTPS Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Airtable Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="airtableForm">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>

    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="number" id="age" name="age"><br><br>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

    <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
    <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount"><br><br>

    <label for="postcode">Postcode:</label>
    <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('airtableForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
  
      // Collect form data
      const formData = {
        name: document.getElementById('name').value,
        age: parseInt(document.getElementById('age').value),
        email: document.getElementById('email').value,
        amount: parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value),
        postcode: document.getElementById('postcode').value
      };

      fetch('https://domain.co.uk:5000/submit', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        alert(data.message); // Display the server's response message
        document.getElementById('airtableForm').reset();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert('Error posting to Airtable:'); // Display the error message
      });
    });
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```